Unable to use NVIDIA L4 GPU Card on Windows Server Hyper-V VMs with DDA
Environment Details:

Host Machine:

OS: Windows Server 2022
GPU: NVIDIA L4  x 3
CPU: Intel Xeon Gold 6542Y (with VT-d enabled)
IOMMU and SR-IOV: Enabled in BIOS


Virtual Machine (VM):

OS: Linux ( Debian 12)
Hyper-V DDA Configurations completing without errors.



Steps Performed:

Check the Current State of the VM
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-VM

Output:
Name                State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status     Version
----                ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------     -------
VM_4.5.12_Build Off   0           0                 00:00:00 正常稼働中 10.0


Set the Automatic Stop Action
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-VM -Name VM_4.5.12_Build -AutomaticStopAction TurnOff


Enable Guest Controlled Cache Types
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-VM -GuestControlledCacheTypes $true -VMName VM_4.5.12_Build


Configure Memory-Mapped I/O Space

Allocated low memory-mapped I/O space:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-VM -LowMemoryMappedIoSpace 3Gb -VMName VM_4.5.12_Build


Allocated high memory-mapped I/O space:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-VM -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 33280Mb -VMName VM_4.5.12_Build




Dismount the GPU from the Host
The GPU was removed from the host using the following command:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice -LocationPath "PCIROOT(9E)#PCI(0100)#PCI(0000)" -Force


Assign the GPU to the VM
The GPU was assigned to the VM using:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Add-VMAssignableDevice -LocationPath "PCIROOT(9E)#PCI(0100)#PCI(0000)" -VMName VM_4.5.12_Build





Start the VM
After completing the DDA setup, the VM was started:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Start-VM -Name VM_4.5.12_Build


Verify the GPU in the Guest OS
Inside the guest OS, the following command was used to check if the GPU is visible:
lspci | grep -i nvidia


Started the VM and checked for the GPU in the guest OS using lspci.



Observed Issue:

The GPU does not appear in the output of lspci inside the Linux VM, despite all configurations completing without errors.
No errors or warnings were observed during the DDA setup process.

Additional Notes:

NVIDIA drivers are installed on Windows server host.
Data Center L4 Driver for Windows 560.94 | Windows Server 2022
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/details/231074/




I wanted to provide an update regarding the issue I faced with NVIDIA L4 GPUs on Windows Server Hyper-V VMs using Discrete Device Assignment (DDA). I was able to resolve this issue successfully by following the guidance provided in the NVIDIA documentation:
Bug #2812853: Microsoft DDA not working with some GPUs.
The problem occurred because GPUs with more than 16 GB of memory require additional MMIO (Memory-Mapped Input/Output) space for proper mapping in the guest VM. Without this configuration, the GPU wouldn't be detected properly in the VM.

Solution:
The workaround involves allocating sufficient HighMemoryMappedIoSpace for the VM based on the GPU's BAR1 memory size and the number of GPUs assigned to the VM. Here's the step-by-step process:

Use the following formula to calculate the required MMIO space:
MMIO space=2×gpu-bar1-memory×assigned-gpus


Where:

gpu-bar1-memory: The amount of BAR1 memory for one GPU (equal to total GPU memory if not specified).
assigned-gpus: The number of GPUs assigned to the VM.


Assign the calculated MMIO space to the VM using the Set-VM PowerShell command on the Hyper-V host.


Example: NVIDIA L4 GPU with 23 GB Memory
For a VM with 1 GPU assigned, where each GPU has 23 GB of BAR1 memory:
MMIO space=2×23 GB×1=46 GB
PowerShell Command:
Run the following on the Hyper-V host to set the required MMIO space:
Set-VM –HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 46GB –VMName <VM_Name>


Example: Multiple GPUs Assigned
For 3 NVIDIA L4 GPUs, each with 23 GB of memory assigned to a single VM:
MMIO space=2×23 GB×3=138 GB
PowerShell Command:
Run the following to set the MMIO space for the VM:
Set-VM –HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 138GB –VMName <VM_Name>


Verification:
Once the MMIO space is configured, reboot the VM and check that the GPU is recognized correctly in the guest VM using tools like nvidia-smi or lspci (for Linux VMs).

I hope this helps anyone facing similar issues. If you have additional questions, feel free to ask!
